# Compile and run freepascal from the Atom editor

Tags: freepascal, atom-editor

I would like to use the Atom editor to learn Pascal. What is the correct way to compile and run a simple Pascal file from the editor? I am on Windows and using the FreePascal compiler.

EDIT:
I got it using the [build](https://atom.io/packages/build) package as follows (thank you @Wosi):

1. Create a folder to hold my Pascal unit HelloWorld.pas
2. In the same folder I placed the following `.atom-build.json` file:

   ```
   {
       "cmd": "CompileAndRun.bat",
       "args": ["{FILE_ACTIVE}"],
       "sh": false,
       "cwd": "{FILE_ACTIVE_PATH}"
   }
   ```
3. And the `CompileAndRun.bat` contents:

   ```
   @echo off
   set FileName=%1
   fpc %FileName%
   set ProgName=%FileName:~0,-5%
   start "" %ProgName%.exe
   ```

Comment: Note that options in the source file can change the generated exe name. Many compiler settings can be set from source using directives. Not all pascal files deliver an exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lazbuild` to compile your projects. That's the easiest way.

Example:

```
C:\development\lazarus\lazbuild.exe MyProject.lpi 
MyProject.exe
```

Click here to learn how to define a build command in Atom: https://atom.io/packages/build#custom-build-command

EDIT: You want to compile and run the currently opened `.pas` file. I strongly don't recommend to do this as a pascal program is usually part of many different `.pas` files beginning with the word `unit`. Usually you are working with projects instead of single `.pas` files.

Nevertheless, the resulting exe file (I assume you're on Windows) is being created in the same folder as the compiled `.pas` file by default.
So you simply need to call the program after compiling it. 
Unfortunately you cannot set `fpc` as the value for `cmd` in your `.atom-build.json` file.
You need to create a batch script that is being called on each build in order to execute both steps.

Create a file called `CompileAndRun.bat` having this content

```
@echo off 
set FileName=%1%
fpc %FileName%
set ProgName=%FileName:~0,-4%
%ProgName%.exe
```

and change the `cmd` value in your `.atom-build.json` file to

```
"cmd": "CompileAndRun.bat",
```

Comment: I already tried the build package but without success. I created a directory to hold my pascal source files and placed the following `.atom-build.json` file in it:
`{
 "cmd": "fpc",
 "sh": true,
 "args": ["{FILE_ACTIVE}"],
}`. When I issue the build command, nothing happens.

Comment: `{FILE_ACTIVE}` is the currently opened file in the editor. You need to point to the project's `.lpi` file.

Comment: The currently opened file is the file I want to compile and run. I create the source file by hand (i.e. HelloWorld.pas). `fpc HelloWorld.pas` works from the command line but not in Atom.

Comment: You cannot compile and run a single `.pas` file. You can only run a project.

Comment: The question then would be how can I run `fpc HelloWorld.pas` and then open the coresponding .exe file from within Atom?

Comment: No, the question is: What do you expect to happen when you execute a pascal unit? Pascal is project based. A unit can be part of many different projects. Define a project and point to it in your build command.

Comment: I have a partial solution now. I edited my question to include it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts! Sadly your solution opens the executable in the build console in atom and that is a problem when user input is expected. Is it possible to open the executable in an external console where user input is possible?

Comment: Change the last line of `CompileAndRun.bat` to `call start %ProgName%.exe`.
The common way to say 'thank you' on StackOverflow is to upvote and/or accepting an answer ;-)

Comment: Sadly, this only opens the console window but does not execute the program. I also had to change the last but one line to `set ProgName=%FileName:~0,-5%`

Comment: I got it: the last line should read `start "" %ProgramName%.exe`